# Play background music would be rejected by Apple Store?

Tags: ios, background

I produced a pedometer program in ios.I want it can work in the background,But I found it would interrupt finally.So I add a AVAudioPlayer and play a silence music when in the background and it works right.

Now I want to submit to the App Store.I worried that I would be rejected.can anybody tell me about sth?
If this way doesn't work,How can I run a pedometer in the background?
(ps)I need to support the device without M7

Answer (score 2):

Yes you will be rejected. You cannot do tricks like that just so you can have your application run in the background. It's like declaring your application as a VOIp app just so you can run background processes.

I suggest you have a legitimate feature that requires the background process otherwise your application will be rejected.

Have a look at [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW22) and search for the heading UIBackgroundModes to see the 6 UIBackgroundMode keys:

*`UIBackgroundModes (Array - iOS) specifies that the app provides specific background services and must be allowed to continue running while in the background. These keys should be used sparingly and only by apps providing the indicated services. Where alternatives for running in the background exist, those alternatives should be used instead. For example, apps can use the signifiant location change interface to receive location events instead of registering as a background location app.`*

I do feel that you can have your application run in the background if you use some location services in your application. Then, quite possibly, could you register your application under the location's key:

*`The app provides location-based information to the user and requires the use of the standard location services (as opposed to the significant change location service) to implement this feature.`*

Comment: I already have some location services.you mean that I only need to add some additional services and I don't have to modify the code?it's the first time I submit app,I can't fully understood you.

Comment: get rid of your silent audio file and whatever youre doing to try and cheat to get your background to run continually in the backround. If you have location services then apply for the `UIBackgroundKey` in your `.plist` file. And this way you can submit to the appstore using the correct background services so that your application doesnt get rejected